# What does defStyleAttr and defStyleRes in context.obtainStyledAttributes() used for?

Tags: android

When I check `QuickContactBadge` in `FrameLayout`, I found following code:

```
 public QuickContactBadge(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    TypedArray a =
        context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                com.android.internal.R.styleable.QuickContactBadge, defStyle, 0);

    mMode = a.getInt(com.android.internal.R.styleable.QuickContactBadge_quickContactWindowSize,
            QuickContact.MODE_MEDIUM);

    a.recycle();

    init();

    mBadgeBackground = getBackground();
}
```

I don't really catch the meaning of `defstyle` and `0` parameter in `obtainStyledAttributes()`. I have looked up reference, but still don't know what it used for.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.Theme.html#obtainStyledAttributes(android.util.AttributeSet,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int)) says:

> **defStyleAttr**   An attribute in the current theme that contains a reference to a style resource that supplies defaults values for the StyledAttributes. Can be 0 to not look for defaults.
>
> **defStyleRes**    A resource identifier of a style resource that supplies default values for the StyledAttributes, used only if defStyleAttr is 0 or can not be found in the theme. Can be 0 to not look for defaults.

"Can be 0 to not look for defaults." If you set this to 0 then it's not going to try to grab default values for the style attributes. It does seem a little counter-intuitive, why overload this method if you can just pass in a 0... but I think it is so you can tell it not to look in `defStyleAttr` for defaults but *do* tell it to look in `defStyleRes` for defaults, and vice versa.