# How to stop my preference screen giving a different font size to a custom made preference

Tags: android, android-preferences

Currently my settings activity gives me two font sizes. One text size for all the predefined preferences and one for a custom preference. The preferences xml does look like this. The custom preference extended from Dialog Preference.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="changemode"
    android:title="@string/change_mode"
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:summary="@string/change_mode_summary"
    />

<org.myapp.settings.NumberPickerPreference
    android:id="@+id/pref_num_picker_pref"
    android:key="@string/number_of_uploads"
    android:title="@string/number_of_uploads"
    />


</PreferenceScreen>
```

What is the reason for this? Since none of the preferences has a predefined text size, is there a way to fix this without adding a textsize attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inflate or create your own (Text)Views, you should make sure they have the same styling as default implementations.

From [this source layout](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/preference_widget_seekbar_material.xml) it seems like they use textAppearanceMedium for titles and textAppearanceSmall for summaries.

So, in your custom layout for a title you should use

```
<!-- for title -->
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
<!-- for summary or description -->
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
```

If you create Views only pramatically (which you probably shouldn't in this case), you can use

```
// for title
titleView.setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_DeviceDefault_Medium);
// for summary
titleView.setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_DeviceDefault_Small);
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @MichaelZet's answer, I faced similar situation with PreferenceScreen element that had 3 sub elements a switchPreference, a List Preference and a customTimePreference. 
The customTimePreference was however a custom class extending DialogPreference. The issue was that first 2 entries (switchPreference, ListPreference) had their title, summary textSize small/same but the customTimePreference's title was large comparing to previous two elements.

The problem was, my customTimePreference's super constructor(DialogPreference constructor) was having a defStyleAttr parm which is the default styling for both the PreferenceScreen's sub element(3rd screen item) and the clicked popup dialogPreference(customTimePreference) and I was passing in a value of 0 for that attribute, which states not to look for defaults as per answer given at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6784919/11971304 shown below.

**defStyleAttr** An attribute in the current theme that contains a reference to a style resource that supplies defaults values for the StyledAttributes. Can be 0 to not look for defaults.

**defStyleRes** A resource identifier of a style resource that supplies default values for the StyledAttributes, used only if defStyleAttr is 0 or can not be found in the theme. Can be 0 to not look for defaults.

passing in the android.R.attr.dialogPreferenceStyle made it use the default styling on the PrefrenceScreen and comply with look of other elements title size.

```
 <PreferenceScreen android:title="Settings">
        <SwitchPreference
            android:defaultValue="..."
            android:key="..."
            android:summary="Switch Summary"
            android:title="Enable Switch" />
        <ListPreference
            android:dialogTitle="Please Select"
            android:entries="@array/list_ids"
            android:entryValues="@array/list_values"
            android:key="..."
            android:title="Selection List popup" />

        <com.android.example.customTimePreference
            android:key="..."
            android:title="Clock Dialog popup"/>
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

```
public TimePreference(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public TimePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        //this(context, attrs, 0);       //default not supplied causing incorrect textSize
        this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.dialogPreferenceStyle);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public TimePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.picker = null;
        setPositiveButtonText(R.string.ok);
        setNegativeButtonText(R.string.cancel);
        this.calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        this.context = context;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In constructor for your class for custom dialog (the one that extends DialogPreference) you have to specify

```
R.attr.dialogPreferenceStyle
```

for example:

```
public class YourPreference extends DialogPreference {

    public YourPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, R.attr.dialogPreferenceStyle);
    }
 (...) 
}
```